# UIButton Custom Font not showing

Tags: objective-c, ios, fonts, uibutton

I've checked out the other similar questions and done what's listed in those, I think, but my custom font is still not showing on a UI button.

The font is in the project, and it is appearing correctly in my UITableViewCells, so I know the font works fine.

I'm loading the view, and assigning the font to the button, but when I run the app it's not showing up the correct font.

FirstViewController.h

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    ...    
    UIButton *searchButton;
    ...
}

...
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *searchButton;
...

@end
```

Then I've got this in FirstViewController.m

```
@synthesize searchButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    

    self.searchButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"FontFile" size: 11.0 ];
}
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Make sure the searchButton is hooked-up in IB.

Comment: Check that your searchButton property is connected in the interface file.

Comment: Is that right clicking, and dragging the Referencing Outlet to the file's owner, then picked "searchButton" from the popup? in IB

Comment: Ooh yes it is! I accidentally attached the button to the view first, which caused many problems. But now it's solved! @Jamihash do you want to answer it so I can tick your answer.

Thanks to you both though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jamihash pointed out, I hadn't hooked up the button from IB to the code. Doing that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.searchButton setTitle:@"ButtonTitle" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```